# How do http proxies determine https traffic with a single port?

Tags: ssl, proxy, http, https

If a proxy receives the tcp packet, then the destination ip address and port are that of the proxy.  In that case, I imagine the only way a proxy can still resolve the intended destination is either through routing the source ip address/port or through the host field in the http header.  Is this correct?

In both Fiddler and Charles http proxies, I noticed that the tool accepts both http and https connections through a single port that you can specify.  What do these tools do to tell the difference between the two types of connections?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

HTTP requests consist of a "GET", "PUT", or similar verb. HTTPS requests consist of a "CONNECT" request, since the browser is asking the proxy to make a connection. The proxy determines the address to connect to because it's the parameter to the CONNECT request.

See the Wikipedia entries on [HTTP tunnel](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_tunnel#HTTP_CONNECT_Tunneling). Also see [this link](http://www.forensicswiki.org/wiki/Proxy_server#HTTP_proxies) which shows some actual HTTP and HTTPS proxy traffic.